# json schema maximize value based on other property

Tags: json, jsonschema

I have a `draft7` schema.
Two required properties are `totalSizeOfFarm` and `totalAreaGrass`, both are type `number` and have `exclusiveMinimum` of 0.

I want the maximum of `totalAreaGrass` not to exceed the value of `totalSizeOfFarm`.
Can this be done?

I've been looking at `if..then` but don't understand how to get the value of `totalSizeOfFarm`.

Please advice.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use the specific value of a number from a JSON instance in your schema.
What you describe is validation business logic, which is beyond the remit of JSON Schema.

If you had specific values, like those you would put in an enum, you can do things based on specific values up front, but not dynamically from the JSON instance you are validating.

That said, there's nothing to stop you adding your own key word, and using the interface for performing your own function based on that keyword. Not all libraries support such things (ajv does), AND this will make your JSON Schema no longer useable by others, which may be a consideration.